# How do you say "The snake is hissing at the man."?

Tags: prépositions, verbes, zoologie

How do you say "The snake is hissing at the man."?

Is it « Le serpent siffle sur l'homme. » or « Le serpent siffle vers l'homme. » or is a different preposition used?

I have looked at various French dictionaries but I still can't find an answer.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

"sur" ou "vers" me semblent très peu naturels. Je traduirais plutôt "le serpent menace l'homme en sifflant". Ou peut-être "le serpent siffle l'homme", mais l'usage transitif de siffler me semble inhabituel pour un animal. On dit "siffler un acteur" ou "siffler une fille". Mais c'est un peu différent.

Comment: This is the correct answer. It's one of many cases where English and French don't use the same aspect of the sentence for the verb.

Answer (score 2):

"Sur" wouldn't do. "Vers" is a possible choice; one instance of this usage can be found in Google Books (recent origin).

- ([ref., De Goupil à Margot, 2021](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/De_Goupil_%C3%A0_Margot/JChVEAAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22siffle+vers%22&pg=PT41&printsec=frontcover)) Au cours de quelle lutte géante avec un grand serpent qui siffle vers sa trompe, son énergie flageolante la livre-t-elle à son ennemi ? Non, c'est un bruit, un bruit souterrain, un grattement sourd, presque imperceptible,

Comment: This isn't a very accurate translation (admittedly, there is no perfectly accurate translation, because French and English can't express exactly the same levels of details about the snake's behavior). “*Siffle vers …*” is simply directional and does not have the same antagonistic connotation as “hisses at”. (It doesn't help that “*siffler*”, which is the correct verb to denote the sound, is not intrinsically antagonistic like “hiss”.)

Comment: @Gilles'SOnousesthostile' True,  the French translation might appear to be missing something; but the defect, if anything appreciable in the least,  is to be sought exclusively in the preposition; it is this element only that can carry the idea of antagonism, and yet only contextually:  SOED, "**10** In the direction of, towards; so as to reach or attack". For snakes "siffler" carries as much the idea of would-be "antagonism" as "hiss", as the hissing as concerns snakes is of a particular sort known to express not really  hatred but disapproval, fear, annoyance; (1/2)

Comment: @Gilles'SOnousesthostile' it is merely defensive, not offensive, in contrast to the growl of a mean dog while attacking. I think this is just an impression induced by the fact that "at" is also used to connote adversity (unlike "vers"), but this interpretation is subject to context (she smiled at him). (2/2)

Answer (score 2):

Je dirais ***contre*** en pensant à [*après*](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/25642/la-syntaxe/les-prepositions/preposition-devant-un-nom/expressions-formees-avec-apres), plus précisément à ces emplois familiers comme *crier après* (et au LBU je lis qu'on a *siffler après* en Belgique) avec l'idée de colère ; on trouve quelques [exemples](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=serpent%20siffle%20%C3%A0%2Cserpent%20siffle%20sur%2Cserpent%20siffle%2Csiffle%20contre&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cserpent%20siffle%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csiffle%20contre%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cserpent%20siffle%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csiffle%20contre%3B%2Cc0) du verbe *siffler* avec la préposition *contre* dans un contexte comparable, soit une [oie](https://books.google.ca/books?id=chE7AAAAcAAJ&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&dq=%22siffle%20contre%22&pg=PA92#v=onepage&q=%22siffle%20contre%22&f=false) qui « siffle contre quiconque les [ses oisons] approche de trop près » ou dans le contexte d'une [traduction](https://books.google.ca/books?id=bedWAAAAMAAJ&q=%22serpent%20siffle%20contre%22&dq=%22serpent%20siffle%20contre%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjv2czJ_O36AhXFUjUKHWoXAwgQ6AF6BAgFEAI) concernant une vipère (« *...contre son éventuel adversaire* »).

Étrangement, j'ai beaucoup de mal à identifier une préposition usuelle dans un registre neutre pour introduire un complément à l'emploi intransitif, alors qu'avec un verbe comme [*japper*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/japper) je trouve la préposition *après* des plus naturelle. J'ai envie de formuler différemment en évoquant la position, la conséquence ou la simultanéité etc. avec *devant, à la vue de, en présence de, en réaction à*.

Comment: On a du mal à trouver une préposition parce qu'en fait, il faudrait [traduire la préposition par un verbe](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/51518) et le verbe par un complément.

Comment: "Siffler après" en Belgique veut dire appeler, attirer l'attention en sifflant (sur le même modèle, qu'appeler après quelqu'un, demander après quelqu'un). Je peux concevoir d'un contexte où des serpents "siffleraient après", mais c'est sans agression: les jeunes serpents sifflaient après leur mère qui venait de quitter le nid.

D'un point de vue belge, la préposition naturelle pour la cible d'un acte agressif serait "sur" : Il crie souvent sur ses enfants, mon chien aboie beaucoup trop sur les passants, le serpent lui sifflait dessus à chaque fois qu'elle s'approchait de son nid

Comment: Contre est la préposition préférée par les français pour ce dernier usage, d'autant que je puisse le déterminer.

Comment: @Gilles'SOnousesthostile' Ce que tu expliques m'arrive souvent en traduisant de l'anglais, merci d'avoir mis des mots là-dessus ; assez généralement quand je suis pris avec le genre d'hésitation dont je parle et que rien ne semble usuel, je « remonte en amont » syntaxiquement ou je passe d'un niveau plus spécifique à une formulation plus générale ou inversement. Par ailleurs que dis-tu de _japper après/contre_ ; vois-tu ça comme plus figé de sorte que le réaménagement dont tu parles n'est pas nécessaire ?

Comment: @Eauquidort Merci ! La préposition _sur_ est vraiment inusitée pour moi, mais _dessus_ passe mieux. J'ai vu _sur_ avec d'autres verbes dans ma recherche et c'était pas belge et je trouvais ça inusité pour moi, possiblement _s'énerver sur quelqu'un_ ou un verbe du genre. Je ne trouve pas le concept d'agression que toi et Gilles évoquez nécessairement pertinent, je vois ça essentiellement comme une direction. J'ai pensé aussi à _en direction de_ ou _à l'endroit de_, mais c'est meilleur quand c'est sous la forme _à mon endroit_ ou _dans ma direction_ et bien moins quand c'est générique...

Comment: @Eauquidort Est-ce qu'on peut dire généralement que l'affinité prépositionnelle est régionale ? Ou c'est la syntaxe non naturelle ou calquée de l'anglais qui déclenche des réflexes régionaux ?

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to translate this sentence exactly because you can't just map the structure of the English sentence into French. It's one of many cases where English and French idiomatically take a different part of the meaning to serve as the verb.

The most common such case is expressing movement, where English tends to express the manner through a verb and the direction through a particle, whereas French tends to express the direction through a verb and the manner through a complement. For example:

> (en) He *climbed* **up** the stairs.
> (fr) Il **a monté** l'escalier *en courant*.

To come back to the specific question, “The snake is hissing at the man” conveys that the snake is antagonizing the man, and that it is doing so through a hissing noise as well as an implied stance. The preposition “at” does the main job of conveying the antagonism. In French, we would tend to use the verb to express the antagonism, and optionally a complement to indicate the noise. French requires a slightly stronger commitment to the nature of the antagonism: there is no exact equivalent to the vagueness of “[make a noise] at”. Thus here are a few possibilities:

> Le serpent se tourne contre l'homme et siffle.
> Le serpent confronte l'homme en sifflant.
> Le serpent menace l'homme en sifflant.   ([propoed by Rémi](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/51518))

If it's not critical to mention the hissing, it can be omitted in French.

Answer (score 0):

I would say : "Le serpent siffle sur l'homme". In the same fashion as "Le chien aboie sur l'homme".

This example can be found in the french literature :

- "Pour qui sont ces serpents qui sifflent sur vos têtes ?" - Jean Racine, Andromaque ([Source](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/1257665-pour-qui-sont-ces-serpents-qui-sifflent-sur-vos-t-tes))

Comment: [Dieux, quels affreux regards elle jette sur moi !
Quels démons, quel serpents traîne-t-elle après soi ?
Hé bien, filles d'enfer, vos mains sont-elles prêtes ?
Pour qui sont ces serpents qui sifflent sur vos têtes ?] Le sens montre que les serpents ne sifflent pas dans la directions des personnes à qui Oreste s'adresse, mais qu'ils reposent sur leurs têtes tout en sifflant.
 https://cocorico.com/images/cocorico-mucha-id.jpg

Comment: https://www.bing.com/images/search?view=detailV2&ccid=JyJmEXJa&id=AA973D039C48414FF125AE0F7A359444573D04FB&thid=OIP.JyJmEXJa1s33NsSo2DayMgHaEv&mediaurl=https%3A%2F%2Fi.pinimg.com%2F736x%2Ff0%2F90%2F17%2Ff090177dc4b7c4188224abb45cf8a405.jpg&cdnurl=https%3A%2F%2Fth.bing.com%2Fth%2Fid%2FR.27226611725ad6cdf736c4a8d836b232%3Frik%3D%252bwQ9V0SUNXoPrg%26pid%3DImgRaw%26r%3D0&exph=471&expw=735&q=andromaque%2c+o%c3%b9+sont+les+serpents&simid=608047497084826933&form=IRPRST&ck=A87F436E239DD7AF50D8A87B6846E46C&selectedindex=1&ajaxhist=0&ajaxserp=0&vt=0&sim=11